# compute gc content for each sequence and return a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have a list called "self.__sequences" with some DNA sequences, and the following is part of that list

```
['AAAACATCAGTATCCATCAGGATCAGTTTGGAAAGGGAGAGGCAATTTTTCCTAAACATGTGTTCAAATGGTCTGAGACAGACGTTAAAATGAAAAGGGG\n', 'TTAGAAACTATGGGATTATTCACTCCCTAGGTACTGAGAATGGAAACTTTCTTTGCCTTAATCGTTGACATCCCCTCTTTTAGGTTCTTGCTTCCTAACA\n', 'CTGAGTAAATCATATACTCAATGATTTTTTTATGTGTGTGCATGTGTGCTGTTGATATTCTTCAGTACCAAAACCCATCATCTTATTTGCATAGGGAAGT\n', 'CTGCCAGCACGCTGTCACCTCTCAATAACAGTGAGTGTAATGGCCATACTCTTGATTTGGTTTTTGCCTTATGAATCAGTGGCTAAAAATATTATTTAAT\n', 'ACTTATATTATGTTGACACTCAAAAATTTCAGAATTTGGAGTATTTTGAATTTCAGATTTTCTGATTAGGGATGTACCTGTACTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT\n', 'TTTGTTCTTTTTGTAATGGGGCCAGATGTCACTCATTCCACATGTAGTATCCAGATTGAAATGAAATGAGGTAGAACTGACCCAGGCTGGACAAGGAAGG\n', 'AAGAGGTAAAGGAAACAGACTGATGGCTGGAGAATTTGACAACGTATAAGAGAATCTGAGAATTCTTTTGAAAAATACTCAAATTTCCAGCCAAGATAGA\n', 'ACACTTGAGCATTAAGAGGAAACACCAAGGAAACAGATTTTAGGTCAAGAAAAAGAAGAGCTCTCTCATGTCAGAGCAGCCTAGAGCAGGAAAGTGCTGT\n', 'ACATCTATGCCCACCACACCTNGGTATGCANTGATGCTCATGAGATGGGAGGTGGCTACAGATTGCTCCATATAGAAATGTTACCTAGCATGTTAAAGAT\n']
```

I want to compute the gc conent for each DNA sequence and returns a dictionary with DNA:gc content. For example, something like that:

```
{(AAAACATCAGTATCCATCAGGATCAGTTTGGAAAGGGAGAGGCAATTTTTCCTAAACATGTGTTCAAATGGTCTGAGACAGACGTTAAAATGAAAAGGGG:0.5), (TTAGAAACTATGGGATTATTCACTCCCTAGGTACTGAGAATGGAAACTTTCTTTGCCTTAATCGTTGACATCCCCTCTTTTAGGTTCTTGCTTCCTAACA:0.33)}
```

`gc content= (Count(G) + Count(C)) / (Count(A) + Count(T) + Count(G) + Count(C))`

I write the following code but it gives me nothing!

```
def get_gc_content(self):
    for i in range (len(self.__sequence)):
        if seq[i] in self.__sequence:
             return (seq.count('G')+seq.count('C'))/float(seq.count('G')+seq.count('C')+seq.count('T')+seq.count('A'))
```

Can anyone help me to improve my code?

Comment: your function doesn't do anything towards creating a dict. How have you been attempting to create this dict?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you analyze DNA (not RNA, etc) and `strip()` newlines and spaces from your sequences, `seq.count('A') + seq.count('G') + seq.count('C') + seq.count('T')` would always equal `len(seq)`.

Note that `seq.some_method_name` operates on the *whole* sequence. You don't need the `for` loop that iterates over sequence elements at all.

The `i in self.__sequence` is always `False` (you pick an integer and see if it belogs to to sequence of four possible letters), so it does nothing.

The first `return` inside the loop will break the loop.

Here's a piece of code that seems to work:

```
def getContentOf(target_list, seq):
  # add a 1 for each nucleotide in target_list
  target_count = sum(1 for x in seq if x in target_list)
  return float(target_count) / len(seq)
```

Answers look sensible:

```
>>> getContentOf(['G', 'C'], 'AGCT')
0.5
>>> getContentOf(['G', 'C'], 'AGCTATAT')
0.25
>>> _
```

So what you need is something like `{seq: getContentOf(['G', 'C'], seq)}`

BTW the sequences you gave in your post seem to have different G+C content than your examples state.

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
self.myDict = {}

def create_dna_dict(self):
    for i in seq:
        if i in self.__sequence:
            self.myDict[i] = (seq.count('G') + seq.count('C')) / float(seq.count('G') + seq.count('C') + seq.count('T') + seq.count('A'))
```

a few things though:

- Are you sure `seq` shouldn't be `self.seq`?
- `__sequence` is a very odd variable name. It seems unconventional.
- In the example of the dict you want, you have an incorrect dict
  syntax

I am quite sure that you're dict, with it's tuples and lack of strings:

```
{(AAAACATCAGTATCCATCAGGATCAGTTTGGAAAGGGAGAGGCAATTTTTCCTAAACATGTGTTCAAATGGTCTGAGACAGACGTTAAAATGAAAAGGGG:0.5), (TTAGAAACTATGGGATTATTCACTCCCTAGGTACTGAGAATGGAAACTTTCTTTGCCTTAATCGTTGACATCCCCTCTTTTAGGTTCTTGCTTCCTAACA:0.33)}
```

Should look like this, with those brackets removed and the keys are strings:

```
{"AAAACATCAGTATCCATCAGGATCAGTTTGGAAAGGGAGAGGCAATTTTTCCTAAACATGTGTTCAAATGGTCTGAGACAGACGTTAAAATGAAAAGGGG":0.5, "TTAGAAACTATGGGATTATTCACTCCCTAGGTACTGAGAATGGAAACTTTCTTTGCCTTAATCGTTGACATCCCCTCTTTTAGGTTCTTGCTTCCTAACA":0.33}
```